# SparkSQL : How to sum two time-series data-sets with different timestamps

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have two data-sets of time-series data.I need to sum up these two data-sets using  probably some sort of windowing approach 
**Timestamps are different for the two datasets**
The result would be the sum of "value" fields from both datasets, which falls within the window of the result dataset.

Is there any builtin functions in Spark to do this easily?or else how can I achieve this in the best possible way

```
DataSet-1 
 raw_data_field_id | date_time_epoch | value
-------------------+-----------------+-----------
                23 |   1528766100068 |       131
                23 |   1528765200058 | 130.60001
                23 |   1528764300049 |     130.3
                23 |   1528763400063 |       130
                23 |   1528762500059 | 129.60001
                23 |   1528761600050 |     129.3
                23 |   1528760700051 | 128.89999
                23 |   1528759800047 | 128.60001

DataSet-2
 raw_data_field_id | date_time_epoch | value
-------------------+-----------------+-----------
                24 |   1528766100000 |       41
                24 |   1528765200000 |       60
                24 |   1528764300000 |       30.03
                24 |   1528763400000 |       43
                24 |   1528762500000 |       34.01
                24 |   1528761600000 |       29.36
                24 |   1528760700000 |       48.99
                24 |   1528759800000 |       28.01
```

Comment: Union the dataframes first, then sort by time column and then use the time window function ( need spark 2 at least) http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/introduction-to-spark-two-part-5/

Comment: @sramalingam24, thankyou somuch. I shall try the solution you suggested

Comment: Cool no problemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her is an example

```
scala> d1.show
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
|raw_data_field_id|     date_time_epoch|    value|
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
|               23|2018-06-12 01:15:...|    131.0|
|               23|2018-06-12 01:00:...|130.60001|
|               23|2018-06-12 00:45:...|    130.3|
|               23|2018-06-12 00:30:...|    130.0|
|               23|2018-06-12 00:15:...|129.60001|
|               23|2018-06-12 00:00:...|    129.3|
|               23|2018-06-11 23:45:...|128.89999|
|               23|2018-06-11 23:30:...|128.60001|
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+


scala> d2.show
+-----------------+--------------------+-----+
|raw_data_field_id|     date_time_epoch|value|
+-----------------+--------------------+-----+
|               24|2018-06-12 01:15:...| 41.0|
|               24|2018-06-12 01:00:...| 60.0|
|               24|2018-06-12 00:45:...|30.03|
|               24|2018-06-12 00:30:...| 43.0|
|               24|2018-06-12 00:15:...|34.01|
|               24|2018-06-12 00:00:...|29.36|
|               24|2018-06-11 23:45:...|48.99|
|               24|2018-06-11 23:30:...|28.01|
+-----------------+--------------------+-----+
scala> d1.unionAll(d2).show
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
|raw_data_field_id|     date_time_epoch|    value|
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
|               23|2018-06-12 01:15:...|    131.0|
|               23|2018-06-12 01:00:...|130.60001|
|               23|2018-06-12 00:45:...|    130.3|
|               23|2018-06-12 00:30:...|    130.0|
|               23|2018-06-12 00:15:...|129.60001|
|               23|2018-06-12 00:00:...|    129.3|
|               23|2018-06-11 23:45:...|128.89999|
|               23|2018-06-11 23:30:...|128.60001|
|               24|2018-06-12 01:15:...|     41.0|
|               24|2018-06-12 01:00:...|     60.0|
|               24|2018-06-12 00:45:...|    30.03|
|               24|2018-06-12 00:30:...|     43.0|
|               24|2018-06-12 00:15:...|    34.01|
|               24|2018-06-12 00:00:...|    29.36|
|               24|2018-06-11 23:45:...|    48.99|
|               24|2018-06-11 23:30:...|    28.01|
+-----------------+--------------------+---------+
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.window
val df = d1.union(d2)
val avg_df = df.groupBy(window($"date_time_epoch", "15 minutes")).agg(avg($"value"))
avg_df.show
+--------------------+-----------------+
|              window|       avg(value)|
+--------------------+-----------------+
|[2018-06-11 23:45...|        88.944995|
|[2018-06-12 00:30...|             86.5|
|[2018-06-12 01:15...|             86.0|
|[2018-06-11 23:30...|        78.305005|
|[2018-06-12 00:00...|79.33000000000001|
|[2018-06-12 00:45...|           80.165|
|[2018-06-12 00:15...|        81.805005|
|[2018-06-12 01:00...|        95.300005|
+--------------------+-----------------+
avg_df.sort("window.start").select("window.start","window.end","avg(value)").show(truncate = false)
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|start              |end                |avg(value)       |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|2018-06-11 23:30:00|2018-06-11 23:45:00|78.305005        |
|2018-06-11 23:45:00|2018-06-12 00:00:00|88.944995        |
|2018-06-12 00:00:00|2018-06-12 00:15:00|79.33000000000001|
|2018-06-12 00:15:00|2018-06-12 00:30:00|81.805005        |
|2018-06-12 00:30:00|2018-06-12 00:45:00|86.5             |
|2018-06-12 00:45:00|2018-06-12 01:00:00|80.165           |
|2018-06-12 01:00:00|2018-06-12 01:15:00|95.300005        |
|2018-06-12 01:15:00|2018-06-12 01:30:00|86.0             |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```